# Did Sweeney Todd’s story appear in the “Newgate Calendar” prior to “The String of Pearls”?

Tags: identification-request, the-string-of-pearls

The character Sweeney Todd, the “demon barber of Fleet Street”, appeared in the “penny dreadful” serial [*The String of Pearls*](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/59828) (1846–1847). The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_String_of_Pearls) on the serial says:

> Sweeney Todd’s story also appears in the Newgate Calendar, originally a bulletin of executions produced by the keeper of Newgate prison, the title of which was appropriated by chapbooks, popular pamphlets full of entertaining, often violent criminal activities.

This is cited to (and plagiarised from) a 2008 article in the *Guardian*:

> Sweeney Todd’s story does appear in the Newgate Calendar, originally a bulletin of executions produced by the keeper of Newgate prison, the title of which was appropriated by chapbooks, popular pamphlets full of entertaining, often violent criminal activities.
>
> <sub>Louise Welsh (19 January 2008). ‘[On a knife edge](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2008/jan/19/classics.film)’. *The Guardian*.</sub>

This claim is hard to check because [so many publications](https://archive.org/search.php?query=Newgate%20Calendar%20AND%20mediatype%3Atexts) used the title “[Newgate Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Newgate_Calendar)”, but I searched several archives and could find no evidence supporting it.

So, is it true that Sweeney Todd’s story appears in a publication under the title “Newgate Calendar”, or indeed anywhere prior to *The String of Pearls*? If not, where could Welsh have got the claim from? The claim appears, for example, in Peter Haining’s [*Sweeney Todd: The Real Story of the Demon Barber of Fleet Street*](https://archive.org/details/sweeneytoddreals0000hain) (1993), but Welsh seems to be aware that Haining’s book is a hoax, so it would be surprising if she relied on him.

*Warning to anyone researching this*: anything published after Haining (1993) needs to be checked to see if it derives from or relies on Haining. A lot of people seem to have fallen for the hoax, so you need to be suspicious of any reference which you have not checked for yourself!

Comment: The Saturday Review of Literature August 1924 also has the claim that the tale is related in the Newgate Calendar. This is in a theatre review so may have been a claim by the promoter/producer. https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=umn.319510019153835&view=1up&seq=94&q1=Todd

Comment: Good find! But note that the piece gives 1842 for the first performance of the play at the Britannia, that is, four years prior to *The String of Pearls*, which makes me suspicious as to the quality of its research. ([*A History of Nineteenth Century Drama 1800–1850*, volume II, p. 364](https://archive.org/details/historyofearlyni0002unse/page/364/mode/2up) gives the date 22 February 1847.)

Comment: I didn’t suppose Miss Benson had carried out any more research than reading her programme. I was only indicating that the idea of NC as a source at least predates Haining.

Comment: Yes, it's a promising lead. [Here's a very similar mention in *The Outlook* for 10 September 1924](https://archive.org/details/sim_new-outlook_1924-09-10_138_2/page/44/mode/2up) — so perhaps the 1924 revival of the play claimed that the story came from the Newgate Chronicle? Sadly I can't find a text, though apparently one was published in 1828.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sources for the *Newgate Calendar* claim

[In a comment](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/21500/did-sweeney-todd-s-story-appear-in-the-newgate-calendar-prior-to-the-string-o#comment32531_21500), Spagirl tracked down the following review of a 1924 performance of the play:

> We have been exhilarated by slightly cooler weather in the desert, and the other evening Gordon, our djinn, took the Princess and ourselves on his broad wings and wafted us in the wink of an eye to Manhattan, depositing us at the Frazee Theatre, where we witnessed an interesting performance of “Sweeney Todd, the Demon Barber of Fleet Street.” This elevating drama, we learn, was first performed at the Britannia Theatre, London, in 1842. The life of the original *Sweeney Todd* is **recorded in The Newgate Calendar**. He was hung by *Jack Ketch*.
>
> <sub>William Rose Benét, writing as ‘W. R. B.’ (30 August 1924). ‘[The Phoenix Nest](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=umn.319510019153835&view=1up&seq=94)’. In *The Saturday Review of Literature*, p. 88. New York.</sub>

Spagirl was astute in suggesting that “we learn” indicates that Benét’s information came from the programme for the play. I found another review of the same production, which explicitly cites the programme for its information:

> […] now an English melodrama, “Sweeney Todd, the Barber of Fleet Street; or, The String of Pearls,” by [George Dibdin Pitt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Dibdin_Pitt), is most amusingly presented in New York. Whether or not we accept the **statement on the programme** that this was the first play to be given at a “command performance” before Queen Victoria, the method in which it is now enacted makes tolerable and highly entertaining a drama which would be too absurdly gory if it were given as its creator probably intended.
>
> Sweeney Todd, **we are told**, was a real person, born in the last half of the eighteenth century. A false imprisonment and a long sentence so embittered him against the human race that after his liberation he sought vengeance against mankind. The alluring possibilities of a barber-shop seized his imagination, and he perfected a chair which could be made to lower his lathered customers into the cellar. Once they vanished below, they were never seen again, although dreadful hints—or more than hints—are given as to their fate. It will be enough to say that next to Sweeney’s was the shop and bakery of Mrs. Lovett, famous all over London for her veal pies. It was asserted that a nefarious partnership existed between the neighbors!
>
> <sub>Anon (10th September 1924). ‘[The Demon Barber](https://archive.org/details/sim_new-outlook_1924-09-10_138_2/page/44/mode/2up)’. In *The Outlook* 138:2, p. 45. New York.</sub>

So, putting these together, the producers of the 1924 New York production of the play had claimed in the programme that Sweeney Todd was real and that his crimes had been recorded in the *Newgate Calendar*. Of course, theatrical publicity is prone to exaggeration and stretching the truth: it is hard to see how [Jack Ketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Ketch) (died 1686) could have hanged Sweeney Todd if he was “born in the last half of the eighteenth century”, as claimed, and the 1842 date for the first production of Pitt’s play at the Britannia Saloon in Hoxton is also wrong (it was 1847). I suggest that the producers might have derived the *Newgate Calendar* claim from the 1850 text of *The String of Pearls*, where the anonymous author writes:

> In answer to the many inquiries that have been, from time to time, made regarding the fact of whether there ever was such a person as Sweeney Todd in existence, we can unhesitatingly say, that there certainly was such a man; and the record of his crimes is still to be found in the **chronicles of criminality** of this country.
>
> <sub>Anon (1850). [*The String of Pearls; or, the Barber of Fleet Street*, preface](https://archive.org/details/stringofpearlsor00ryme/page/n5/mode/2up). London: R. Lloyd.</sub>

If you believed this claim (or even if you didn’t, but found it useful for publicity purposes), it would be natural to take “chronicles of criminality” as a disguised reference to the *Newgate Calendar*, since substantial parts of the story take place in and around Newgate Prison.

But even if my speculation here is wrong, these reviews show that there existed a tradition that Sweeney Todd’s story appeared in the *Newgate Calendar* prior to Peter Haining’s hoax.

#### Sources for *The String of Pearls*

The story seems to have originated as an urban legend in Paris. The earliest version that I found is from a **1612** guidebook by [Jacques du Breul](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_du_Breul) (1528–1614), a Benedictine monk at the Abbey of Saint-Germain-des-Prés in Paris. In his version, a pastry-cook and a barber collaborated in a single murder.

> *De la maison des Marmousets.*†
>
> C’est de temps immemorial, que le bruit a couru qu’il y avoit en la Cité de Paris, ruë des Marmousets, un patissier meurtrier, lequel ayant occis en sa maison un homme, aydé à ce par un sien voisin Barbier, faignant raser la barbe : de la chair d’iceluy faisoit des pastez qui le trouvoient meilleurs que les aultres, d’autant que la chair de l’homme est plus delicate, à cause de la nourriture, que celle des autres animaux. Et que celà ayant este descouvert, la Cour de Parlement ordonna qu’oultre la punition du Patissier, sa maison seroit razee, & outre ce une pyramide ou colomne erigee audict lieu, en memoire ignominieuse de ce detestable faict: delaquelle reste encores part & portion en ladicte rue des Marmousets.
>
> Le Roy François premier par ses patentes octroyees à Maistre Pierre Belut, Conseiller en Parlement pour y rebatir declare la demolition avoir este faicte pour grand crime commis en icelle : Mais il ne le specifie point, pource qu’on ne luy representa pas le susdit Arrest de la Cour. Tant y a que la place est demeuree vague plus de cent ans. Et pour preuve, je rapporteray îcy les susdictes lettres du Roy François, que m’a communiquees Monsieur Nicolas Belut, Conseillier au Thresor, fils du dit Pierre Belut, & detenteur de ladicte maison des Marmousets.
>
> *The house of the Marmosets.*
>
> From time immemorial, the rumour has circulated that there lived in the City of Paris, on the street of the Marmosets, a murderous pastry-cook, who had slain a man in his house, assisted by one of his neighbours, the barber, feigning to shave his beard: from the flesh of the same he made pies which were found to be better than the others, as human flesh is more delicate, because of its nourishment, than that of other animals. And after all this had been found out, the Court of Parliament ordered that besides the punishment of the pastry-cook, his house would be razed, and also an obelisk or column erected in its place, in ignominious memory of this detestable deed, and which still remains part and parcel of the street of the Marmosets.
>
> King Francis I, by his letters patent granted to Master Pierre Belut, counsellor in Parliament, to rebuild there, declares that the demolition was done for a great crime committed there. But he does not specify what, because no-one could produce the aforesaid order of the Court. Nonetheless, the place remained empty for more than a hundred years. And as proof, I will reproduce the above-mentioned letters from King Francis, communicated to me by Mr. Nicolas Belut, counsellor to the Treasury, son of the same Pierre Belut, and owner of the house of Marmosets.
>
> <sub>Jacques du Breul (1612). [*Theatre des antiquitez de Paris*, pp. 110–111](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_E49nj3pO7McC/page/109/mode/2up). Paris: Pierre Chevalier.</sub>
>
> <sub>† ‘[Marmousets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmousets)’ was a nickname for the ministers of Charles VI (1368–1422).</sub>

Follow the [link](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_E49nj3pO7McC/page/109/mode/2up) to read the letters patent, which are dated January 1536. It’s clear that by that date there was no written record of whatever had happened to cause the house to be demolished and the memorial erected on the site, and you can see that the functionary who prepared the letters patent was skeptical that there had ever been an order prohibiting building on the vacant site, let alone an episode of cannibalism: he refers to it as a “pretendu Arrest”, that is, an “alleged order”.

In **1742** [Jean-Aymar Piganiol de la Force](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Aimar_Piganiol_de_La_Force) retold the story in his guidebook to Paris. This is closely based on du Breul’s account, but the story has grown in the telling: now there are multiple victims.

> Auprès de l’Eglise de la Madeleine est une rue longe, mais étroite nommée *la rue des Marmousets*, qui prend depuis la rue de la Juiverie, & va jusqu’a la porte du Cloître Nôtre-Dame. Elle a pris son nom d’une maison ou Hôtel qu’on appelloit en 1300. 1400. & 1475. *Domus Marmosetorum*. On ne sçait si l’on doit regarder comme un conte, ou comme une vérité une tradition fort ancienne qui veut qui’il y ait eu autrefois dans cette rue un Barbier qui coupoit la gorge à quelques-uns de ceux qu’il rasoit ; & puis livroit leurs corps à un Patissier qui en faisoit des patés, dont il avoit un débit surprenant. Ce crime ayant été découvert, le Barbier & le Patissier furent punis de mort, leurs maisons rasées, & une Piramide érigée en leur place. On n’a point de preuves positives de tous ces faits ; mais il est constant que pendant plus de cent ans il y a eu dans cette rue une place vuide, & sur laquelle le Propriétaire ne croyoit pas qu’il lui fût permis de bâtir. *Pierre Belut* Conseiller au Parlement à qui elle appartenoit, en demanda la permission à François I. & ce Prince par des Lettres Patentes du mois de Janvier de l’an 1536 lui *permit d’y faire bâtir, & reédifier une maison pour être habitée, ainsi que les autres maisons de Paris. Nonobstant, ajoûtent-elles, ledit prétendu Arrêt, Sentence du Prevôt de Paris, condamnation de l’Hôtel de notre dite Ville, & autres quelconques qui sur ce pourroient être intervenus : ausquels Arrêts, Sentence & condamnation avons de nôtre autorité dérogé, & dérogeons par ces présentes, & sur ce imposons silence perpétuel à nôtre Procureur présent & advenir*. Quoi-qu’on ne trouve nulle part ni informations, ni Arrêt qui parlent de ce prétendu crime, il ne s’enfuit nullement qu’il soit faux ; car dans les crimes atroces & extraordinaires, il a été toujours d’usage, & il l’est encore aujourd’hui, d’en jetter au feu les informations & la procédure, pour ne point les rendre croyables : *Nam sunt crimina qua ipsa magnitudine fidem non impetrant*.
>
> Near the Madeleine is a long narrow street called *the street of the Marmousets*, which runs from the Jewish quarter to the entrance to the cloister of Nôtre-Dame. It took its name from a house or Hotel that was known in 1300, 1400, and 1475 as *Domus Marmosetorum*. I do not know if I should regard as fiction or fact, a very ancient tradition which holds that there was formerly in this street a barber, who cut the throats of some of those he shaved, and then handed their bodies to a pastry-cook who made them into pies, of which he had a surprising output. This crime having been discovered, the barber and the pastry-cook were sentenced to death, their houses razed, and an obelisk erected in their place. There is no positive proof of all these deeds; but it is common knowledge that for more than a hundred years there was a vacant square in this street, on which the owner believed he was forbidden to build. *Pierre Bélut*, counsellor to Parliament, to whom it belonged, asked François I for permission, and this Prince, by letters patent of January 1536 *allowed him to build there, and rebuild a dwelling-house, like the other houses in Paris. Notwithstanding*, they add, *the aforementioned alleged order, the verdict of the Provost of Paris, the condemnation of the Hotel of our said city, and anything else that could have been concerned with this: these orders, verdict and condemnation have by our authority been repealed, and we hereby repeal them, and we impose perpetual silence on this subject on our representative now and forever*. Although there is no record or judgment to be found anywhere that speaks of this alleged crime, it is not necessarily false; because in atrocious and extraordinary crimes, it was always customary, and is still today, to throw records and procedure into the fire, so as not to make them credible: *for they are crimes that by their very enormity are disbelieved*.
>
> <sub>Jean-Aymar Piganiol de la Force (1742). [*Description de Paris*, volume I, pp. 505–507](https://archive.org/details/descriptiondepar01piga/page/504/mode/2up). Paris: Charles-Nicholas Poirion.</sub>

Some time prior to **1793** [Carlo Antonio Delpini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlo_Antonio_Delpini), pantomimist and theatrical manager at Drury Lane and Covent Garden, told the story to the journalist [John Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Williams_(satirist)), claiming it had really happened in Vienna. Note that this version, uniquely, lacks the barber, but it is the first version (that I found) to introduce the motif of the trap-door.

> Delpini told us a Venetian story, which he asserted to be literally true, and which Lord Barrymore meant partially to introduce in a pantomime—the events were these: in the neighbourhood of St. Mark’s there resided a pastry-cook, who became very rich in consequence of selling small meat pies, the flavor and zest of which were uncommonly gratifying; they were sought for so eagerly through the republic, that the man could not find materials to make a number adequate to the general demand. Various were the conjectures as to the contents of those pies; some thought they were veal, some ortolans, and others imagined there might be a mixture of both; every baker endeavoured to make similar luxuries, but all failed. During the progress of this man’s culinary fame, it was observed, that many children had been lost in the city; it was a matter, at last, of public consternation; the police did all they could to discover their retreat, but in vain, and the streets were crowded with bewailing mothers. At length it pleased Heaven to unravel the mysterious evil. One of these pies being opened at the table of a senator, the joint of a child’s finger was found amidst the pastry. This discovery created a common horror; and the idea instantly occurred, that the baker was the monster who had entrapped and destroyed the missing infants: a party of soldiers were immediately ordered to examine the premises, when, after a long search by torch-light, they could find no other proof to justify the presumed guilt, and were on the eve of departure; when suddenly one of their party disappeared and they could not find where, until they seized the baker by the throat, and threatened him with instant death if he did not shew them where their companion was enveloped; the wretch complied, and led them to a sliding trap-door, which covered a deep and gloomy vault, upon which he had heedlessly stepped, and been swallowed up; they descended by means of a bucket, and found the soldier, stretched upon the bodies of various dead children, recently massacred. Upon this unerring testimony of the diabolism, savageness, and (enormity of the cook and his family, the senate ordered the doors and windows of the house to be chained and barred, and surrounded with the army; who joyfully set fire to the building, which, with all in it, was consumed to the ground, and an obelisk raised upon the ashes, significant of the atrocity and the conflagration.
>
> <sub>John Williams, writing as ‘Anthony Pasquin’ (1793). [*The Life of the Late Earl of Barrymore*, pp. 52–53](https://archive.org/details/lifelateearlbar00barrgoog/page/n56/mode/2up). London: H. D. Symonds.</sub>

In **1825** the anonymous ‘**Horrible Affair in the Rue de la Harpe at Paris**’ was published. This has some details that derive from du Breul, such as the vacant lot with the memorial, but moves the action to a different street, and adds the detail of a dog that revealed the crime by attacking the barber. Several sources claim that this had been previously published in *Tell-Tale* magazine in 1823, but I was unable to substantiate that. I won’t quote the whole thing as it is long and poorly written. Follow the [link](https://archive.org/details/terrificregiste00firgoog/page/309/mode/2up) if you want to read it all.

The Wikipedia article on [*The String of Pearls*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_String_of_Pearls) reports a claim that this story was based on a real crime that occurred during the tenure of chief of police [Joseph Fouché](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Fouch%C3%A9) and which was described in his *Archives of the Police*, but this is another fabrication, since there is no such book, and the rue de la Harpe version of the story is clearly derived from that of the rue des Marmousets, which (if anything like it happened at all) took place no later than the fifteenth century.

> In the Rue de la Harpe, which is a long dismal ancient street in the fauxbourg of St. Marcell, is a space or gap in the line of building upon which formerly stood two dwelling houses, instead of which stands now a melancholy memorial, signifying, that upon this spot no human habitation shall ever be erected, no human being ever must reside! […]
>
> After a fruitless search and much altercation, the barber, who had prevailed upon those who had forced in to quit his house, came to the door, and was haranguing the populace, declaring most solemnly his innocence, when the dog suddenly sprang upon him, flew at his throat in such a state of terrific exasperation, that his victim fainted, and was with the utmost difficulty rescued from being torn to pieces. The dog seemed to be in a state of intellectual agony and fury.
>
> It was now proposed to give the animal his way, to see what course he would pursue. The moment he was let loose, he flew through the shop, darting down stairs into a dark cellar, where he set up the most dismal howlings and lamentations.
>
> Lights being procured, an aperture was discovered in the wall communicating to the next house, which was immediately surrounded, in the cellar whereof was found the body of the unfortunate man who had been missing. The person who kept this shop was а patissier. […]
>
> The pastry-cook, whose shop was so remarkable for savoury patties that they were sent for to the Rue de la Harpe, from the most distant parts of Paris, was the partner of this peruquier, and those who were murdered by the razor of the one were concealed by the knife of the other in those very identical patties, by which, independently of his partnership in those frequent robberies, he had made a fortune.
>
> This case was of so terrific a nature, it was made part of the sentence of the law, that besides the execution of the monsters upon the rack, the houses in which they had perpetrated those infernal deeds, should be pulled down, and that the spot on which they stood should be marked out to posterity with horror and execration.
>
> <sub>Anon (1825). ‘[Horrible Affair in the Rue de la Harpe at Paris](https://archive.org/details/terrificregiste00firgoog/page/309/mode/2up)’. In *The Terrific Register; or, Record of Crimes, Judgments, Providences, and Calamities*, p. 310. London: Sherwood, Jones & Co.</sub>

Louis Lurine’s **1844** guidebook to the streets of Paris included an account of the murders at the rue des Marmouzets, expanded from du Breul in a similar manner to that of Piganiol de la Force, quoted above.

> Vers la fin du quatorzième siècle, la maison des Marmouzets était eu bonne renommée dans la vicomté et prévôté de Paris. Un barbier et un pâtissier y tenaient boutique : le pâtissier, qui augmentait chaque jour sa clientelle et sa fortune, se gardait de toute contravention aux ordonnances de la police du Châtelet, tandis que son métier commettait « fautes, mesprentures et déceptions au préjudice du peuple et de la chose publique, au moyen desquelles fautes se peuvent encourir plusieurs inconvénients es corps humains. » On ne lui reprochait pas d’avoir fait un seul pâté *de cairs sursemées et puantes, ni de poisson corrompu*, un seul flanc de lait *tourné et écrêmé*, une seule *rinsole* de porc ladre, une seule tartelette de fromage *moisi*. Il n’exposait jamais de pâtisserie rance ou réchauffée ; il ne confiait pas sa marchandise à des gens de métiers *honteux et déshonnètes*. Aussi estimait-on singulièrement les pâtés qu’il préparait lui-même ; car, malgré la vogue de son commerce, il n’avait qu’un apprenti pour manipuler la pâte, sous prétexte de cacher le secret de l’assaisonnement des viandes.
>
> Son voisin le barbier, baigneur étuviste, avait mérité la faveur du public qui ne tarissait pas en éloges sur son adresse et sa probité ; personne mieux que lui ne *testonnait*, ne rasait, ne saignait, n’étuvait. À peine ses garçons allaient-ils crier par les rues : *les bains sont chauds !* la foule s’y portait, et l’étuve était pleine en un instant ; il connaissait la pratique des drogues autant qu’un *physicien*, et exerçait la chirurgie de même qu’une *mire*. On saluait ses trois bassins de fer-blanc à l’instar d’une madone, et on accourait de toutes parts grossir l’affluence des clients qui faisaient cortège à sa réputation.
>
> Cependant des bruits sinistres avaient plus d’une fois circulé dans la rue des Marmouzets. On parlait d’étrangers massacrés la nuit, et on mon- trait du doigt le ruisseau teint de sang, qui ne provenait pas de saignées faites par le barbier, car on l’eût mis en prison et à l’amende pour n’avoir pas jeté ce sang dans la rivière.
>
> Un soir, des cris perçants sortirent du laboratoire du barbier, chez lequel on avait vu entrer un écolier qui arrivait de l’Allemagne. Cet écolier se traîna sur le seuil, tout sanglant, le cou mutilé de larges blessurés ; on l’entoura, on l’interrogea avec horreur : il raconta comment le barbier l’avait attiré dans son *ouvroir*, en promettant de le raser gratis. En effet, il n’eut pas plutôt livré son menton à l’opérateur, qu’il sentit le rasoir entamer sa peau ; il cria, il se débattit, il détourna les coups de la lame tranchante, et parvint à saisir son ennemi à la gorge, à prendre l’offensive à son tour et à le précipiter dans une trappe ouverte qui attendait une autre victime. En achevant ce récit d’une voix étouffée, il tomba d’épuisement et s’évanouit dans son sang.
>
> Les assistants éclatèrent en malédictions et se signèrent, avant de pénétrer dans ce repaire d’assassinats. On ne trouva plus le barbier, la trappe était refermée ; mais quand on descendit dans une cave commune aux deux boutiques, on surprit le pâtissier occupé à dépecer le corps de son complice qu’il n’avait pas reconnu en l’égorgeant : c’est ainsi qu’il composait ses pâtés, *meilleurs que les autres*, dit le père Dubreul, *d’autant plus que la chair de l’homme est plus délicate, à cause de la nourriture*. En mémoire de ce crime incroyable, la maison fut démolie, et une pyramide expiatoire élevée à l’endroit où ce boucher de chair humaine, qui fut brûlé avec ses pâtés, apprêtait sa délicieuse et atroce pâtisserie. L’arrêt exécuté, la procédure anéantie, le temps n’effaça pas le souvenir du pâtissier homicide qui sert encore d’épouvantail aux petits enfants de la rue des Marmouzets.
>
> Plus de cent ans après l’évènement, la place vide, *appelée anciennement le lieu des Marmouzets, et qui devait à toujours être inhabitée*, appartenait à Pierre Bélut, conseiller au parlement, qui n’osait entreprendre d’y faire bâtir ; il requit une permission du roi qui, par lettres-patentes du mois de janvier 1536, dérogea à *l’arrêt, sentence et condamnation qui sur ce pouvaient être intervenues, donna congé de réédifier cette place et lieu vide, pour être habitée*, et, *sur ce*, imposa *silence perpétuel* au procureur présent et à venir. Il ne fallut pas moins de la formule royale : *car tel est notre bon plaisir*, pour que les murmures du peuple ne se changeassent pas en voies de fait contre l’oeuvre des maçons, quoique la rue des Marmouzets fût *grandement difformée* par cette place vide et cette pyramide en ruine.
>
> <sub>Louis Lurine (1844). [*Les rues de Paris: Paris ancien et moderne*, volume I, pp. 150–152](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1050724c/f172.item). Paris: G. Kugelmann.</sub>

In the same year, **1844**, Lurine’s version of the story was translated into English.

> Barbers, in those days, did not enjoy the best of reputations; and other less honourable but more lucrative occupations, which were frequently united with their ostensible ones, entitled them to consider themselves especially under the protection of the god Mercury. Of one of these knights of the razor, who, towards the close of the fourteenth century, occupied a house in the Rue des Marmouzets, a horrible history remains on record. The house in which he dwelt was one of the best in the street, and went by the name of Maison des Marmouzets. One side was occupied by the barber, and the other by a confectioner; and if the former was celebrated for his skill in heating baths, in bleeding, shaving, and all the other offices of his trade, the latter was no less renowned for the excellence of his pasties. No one could reproach him with having ever sold a pie the meat of which was not of the freshest and best description; his pastry was never stale, nor his cream sour; and he had in consequence acquired a great reputation throughout Paris. Notwithstanding the large number of his customers, he kept only one apprentice, in order, as he said, that the secret of his skill in seasoning pasties might not be divulged. The barber was equally in favour with the public. No sooner did his bath servants appear in the street, proclaiming that *Les bains sont chauds!* than his establishment was crowded, and every bath occupied in an instant. He was famed also for his skill in surgery, and in a knowledge of drugs and simples was considered equal to any physician.
>
> It so happened that sundry strange rumours had from time to time circulated in the Rue des Marmouzets. People talked of shrieks heard in the night, of strangers who had entered the street at eventide but had never been seen to leave it. More than once stains of blood had been noticed upon the stones, blood which could not proceed from the barber’s shop, because he was compelled, under pain of fine and imprisonment, to throw into the river the result of any bloodlettings which he performed. One night, however, piercing cries were heard to issue from the barber’s laboratory, which a poor student from Germany had a short time before been seen to enter. The next moment the student appeared at the door covered with the blood that issued from a frightful wound in his throat. In answer to the inquiries of those who came running to his assistance, he related how the barber had seduced him into his house by a promise of shaving him free of charge; but that he had scarcely seated himself when he felt the razor, instead of ridding him of his beard, cut deep into his throat. He sprang to his feet, averted with difficulty several blows which the assassin aimed at him, and then closing with his foe, succeeded in overcoming him and throwing him through a trap-door which stood open. The wounded man had no sooner finished his narrative than he fainted from exhaustion and loss of blood. The barber’s shop was immediately entered and searched, but the trap-door was closed and the barber not to be found. On farther investigation however they discovered a cellar common to the two shops, in which they surprised the pastry-cook busied cutting up the body of his accomplice, whom he had murdered as soon as he was thrown down the trap-door, without observing or recognising his features. It was thus, as it appeared, that he was in the habit of providing meat for his pasties, “better than any others,” as an old writer, Dubreul, remarks with infinite *naïveté*, “inasmuch as human flesh is the most delicate, by reason of its better nourishment.”
>
> In memory of the monstrous crimes that had been there perpetrated, the house was demolished, and an expiatory monument raised on the spot where it had stood. It was decreed that no other habitation should ever be built on the same ground, and it was not till a century and a half later, that Pierre Belut, a counsellor, obtained letters patent from Francis the First, empowering him to erect a house upon the site of the Maison des Marmouzets.
>
> <sub>Anon (October 1844). ‘[The Streets of Paris](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.30906/page/n447/mode/2up)’. In *Hood’s Magazine and Comic Miscellany*, volume II, pp. 440–441. London: A. Spottiswood.</sub>

This anonymous 1844 translation of Lurine appeared at the right place and time to have been a likely inspiration for *The String of Pearls*, which began to be serialized in *The People’s Periodical and Family Library* in November 1846.